# Specifying default image source for a Vue component

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

I am building a VUE JS based Image viewer which has the following script

```
<script>
import _image from './assets/default.jpg';
    export default {
        name: 'Clickable-Image',
        props:[
            'isSelected',
            'imageSource',
            'imageName',
        ],
        // Component Data.
        data(){
            return {
                defaultImage:_image,                
            }
        },

        // Component Computed Properties
        computed:{
            // Appearance Computation.
            containerStyle : function(){
                return{
                    ui:true,
                    raised:true,
                    very:false,
                    padded:true,
                    blue: !this.isSelected,
                    green: this.isSelected,
                    inverted:true,
                    segment:true,
                }
            },

            // Image to show.
            displayImage(){
                // This is working if I send the raw image URL
                //return "http://i.imgur.com/N9yfg3C.jpg";
                var src = "";
                if(this.imageSource == "")
                    return this.defaultImage;
                else
                    return this.imageSource;


            }

        },

        // Component Methods for Event Handling.
        methods:{
            ToggleSelection :  function() {
                if(this.isSelected)
                    this.isSelected=false;
                else
                    this.isSelected=true;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

What I want to do is to show a default image in the component when no image URL is supplied as an input.

However, in the computed function, I am unable to return a default image. When I return a string with an Image URL (as shown in the code comments) the image is being displayed.

Note : when i "return _image" in my computed displayImage() function, the default image is being shown.

Here is my component template.

```
<template>
    <div v-on:click="ToggleSelection()">
        <div v-bind:class="containerStyle">
            <div class="ui centered card">
                <div class="image">
                    <img v-bind:src="displayImage">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here's my project structure:

[image]

I am using Vue-Cli with webpack-simple template starter. What am I missing here?

Comment: instead of `this.defaultImage;` return the path to the image file like this. `return '/assets/default.jpg'`